# laravel - how to store multiple checkbox

Tags: laravel

i want to store my selected multiple checkbox into my pivot table

```
<template id="roles-template">
    <div class="col-md-12"  v-for="role in list">
        <input type="checkbox" name="role_id[]" value="{{ role.id }}" >
            <span class="form-radio--text">{{ role.name }}</span>
        </input>
    </div>
</template>
```

on my controller, I try to fetch the input and store to database with

```
$role = Role::findOrFail($request->role_id);
$permission->giveRoleTo($role); //store into pivot table
```

but it gives me an error

> Argument 1 passed to App\Role::giveRoleTo() must be instance of App\Role, instance of illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given

anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: dont want to use foreach ?

Comment: foreach in my view? i use `v-for` vuejs in this case

Comment: in your controller you want to save the value of all the check boxes right

Comment: yes i want to save an array data value based on checked boxes

Answer (score 0):

To find many record by ID in one shot you should use.

```
$roles = Role::findMany($request->role_id);
```